# Hide UIMenuController using UIMenuControllerWillShowMenuNotification

Tags: iphone, uitextview, uimenucontroller

I have a UITextView(not editable). When user tries to select text I want to hide the Select | Select All menu.

Is there a way by which I can hide using the Global notification UIMenuControllerWillShowMenuNotification, or is there any other way by which I can hide and Select | Select All menu?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try overriding  (BOOL)canPerformAction:(SEL)action withSender:(id)sender of UIResponder? That controls what menu options are shown in the menu.

Answer (score 0):

I would simply style a `UILabel` to look the way you want.

If the user can't edit the text view, why are you using it instead of a label?

Comment: That's because I still want selectedRange. Basically get the cursor position and then perform some action based on it.

Comment: I see. Disregard my answer then. I'll leave it up just so others don't say the same thing.